# strlen code not working

Tags: c, strlen

Working on this little piece of code, but for some reason it keep crashing the whole time.

Anyone got an idea what i'm doing wrong

```
char *str;
printf("Enter a string\n");
gets(str);
printf("The size of the string is %d", strlen(str));
system("PAUSE");    
return 0;
```

Comment: @Lafexlos While removing the tag from the title is a useful edit, I consider it too minor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not allocated any memory for `str`. Declare a buffer, for example `char str[50]`, but be aware of [buffer overflows](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Buffer_overflow_attack).

Comment: @user3206159 Since this answer helped you, you can accept it by clicking the little checkmark next to it. This will give both you and mdsl some reputation points, and will mark your question as solved. It's not required, but is highly recommended.

Answer (score 2):

You only created an char* pointer which points to random space in memory and you try to do something with it - and that is why your program crashes.

You should create an array of chars:

```
char str[50];
```

or dynamically allocate memory for string with malloc:

```
char* str;
str = (char *)malloc(50*sizeof(char)); // allocate memory
// some operations
free(str);                      // deallocate memory
```

where 50 is your estimated size of buffer.

Comment: One should _always_ check the return value of a `malloc` call. Personally, I always write a simple if to do that: `if ((str = (char *)malloc(50 * sizeof(char))) == NULL) { fprintf(stderr, "Malloc error\n"); exit(1); }`